# not a single-group group function when trying to add two sum() function

Tags: oracle

I have two tables:

```
create table a 
(
  index_ numeric(1),
  value_ numeric(2)
);
create table b 
(
  index_ numeric(1),
  value_ numeric(2)
);
```

Now I want to get the number of these two tables sum,I tried :

```
select sum(value_) - (select sum(value_) from b) from a ;
```

it is not working without group by, how can i do this without group by?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without Group By?

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  (select sum(value_) from a)
  -
  (select sum(value_) from b)
from dual;
```